# Understanding bidirectional relationship from Hibernate documentation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am going through the [Hibernate documentation for bidirectional relationship](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional), in the doc it says that:

**Example 7.21. Bidirectional one to many with many to one side as association owner**

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

> Troop has a bidirectional one to many relationship with Soldier
>   through the troop property. You don't have to (must not) define any
>   physical mapping in the mappedBy side.
>
> To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the
>   owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many
>   to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false. This solution
>   is not optimized and will produce additional UPDATE statements.

**Example 7.22. Bidirectional association with one to many side as owner**

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

I am finding difficulty in understanding this as I am new to Hibernate.

1) What it means when the doc says:
 `You don't have to (must not) define any physical mapping in the mappedBy side.`

2) `@JoinColumn` in 7.22 has same value (troop_fk) for `name` attribute. Can we specify different values? What is the advantage & disadvantages of setting `insertable=false, updatable=false` here?

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bidirectional association. So, if a soldier balongs to a troop, the troop contains the soldier. These are just the two ways of saying the same thing.

In Soldier, you tell how the association is represented in the database: using a join column named troop_fk:

```
@JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
public Troop getTroop() {
```

So, repeating that same information on the other side of this bidirectional association is redundant. You must not do it. By saying

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
```

you're telling Hibernate that `getSoldiers()` is the inverse side of a bidirectional association, and that the way this association is mapped can be found on the `Soldier.troop` property.

Regarding your second question. Once again, the goal is to define a *single*, but bidirectional association. You don't need two different foreign keys to map a single association. So specifying a different name for the join column would make no sense: it would create a different, unidirectional association.

This way of doing is an ugly hack that, AFAIK, is not supported by the JPA spec. The JPA spec mandates that the owner side of a bidirectional OneToMany association is the many side. In fact it creates two unidirectional associations mapped the same way, and tells Hibernate (using insertable = false and updatable = false) to ignore one of them when saving the entity. It will populate soldier.troop when reading a soldier from the database, but whatever you put into soldier.troop will be ignored when saving the soldier. You should avoid this way of doing, IMHO.